# Spring Tools Suite (Eclipse) Database Connection Properties Empty

Tags: eclipse-plugin, database-connection, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to create a new Data Base connection on Spring Tools Suite IDE with SQL Server following the steps described at the official Eclipse documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700344899.html). How ever, I'm not able to set the connection properties since I'm not able to see those, somehow the properties are not visible (refer to attached screenshot) therefor I cannot proceed any further. I've try to update my STS installation but the issue is still there. I've also tried to add the driver definition from Preferences panel but I'm getting the same behavior.

Has anyone else came across this issue and solve it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Data Base Connection Properties Tab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone else come across this issue I've finally solved the problem. My STS installation was missing part of the Eclipse DTP (Database Tool Platform) components. All I had to do was install these components.

You can install them from 'Help' -> 'Install New Software'. Add the main Kepler repository in case you don't have it already ([Kepler Repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/)), select it in 'work with' and check in the Database Development section components. Once you have it installed, restart STS and the Data Base driver definition will prompt the connections properties correctly.

Hope it helps to someone else as well!!